# Magento 2 community edition

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, template, php-7

What are the key differences between Magento 2 Community Edition and Magento 2 Enterprise Edition, and which one is the best fit for your business needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**strong text**
Magento 2 Community Edition (CE) and Magento 2 Enterprise Edition (EE) are two different editions of the Magento 2 platform, and they have different features, functionalities, and licensing models. Here are some key differences between Magento 2 CE and EE:

Features: Magento 2 EE includes all the features of Magento 2 CE, as well as additional enterprise-level features such as advanced marketing and merchandising tools, customer segmentation, advanced search, and content staging and preview.

Support: Magento 2 EE comes with a dedicated account manager and 24/7 technical support, while Magento 2 CE does not offer dedicated support.

Scalability: Magento 2 EE is designed to handle large volumes of traffic and transactions, and it includes advanced features such as database sharding and split database functionality to optimize performance.

Customization: Magento 2 EE includes more customization options and access to the Magento Technical Support Portal for code-level support and guidance.

Pricing: Magento 2 CE is a free, open-source platform, while Magento 2 EE requires a paid license, which is based on the size and complexity of the business.

Which edition is the best fit for your business needs depends on several factors such as the size and complexity of your business, your budget, and the specific features and functionalities you require. If you are a small or mid-sized business with a limited budget, Magento 2 CE may be the best option. However, if you are an enterprise-level business with complex requirements and a need for dedicated support, advanced features, and customization options, Magento 2 EE may be a better fit. It is recommended that you evaluate your business needs and consult with a Magento partner or developer to determine the best option for your specific requirements.

Comment: Please note that  EE split database  is deprecated by Adobe Commerce